# Parse error in where

Tags: haskell

In this code

```
neighbours :: CityMap -> District -> [District]
neighbours (CM (_,rs)) b = mapMaybe neighbour rs
    where neighbour (p,q)
        | b == p    = Just q --parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
        | b == q    = Just p
        | otherwise = Nothing
```

i have parse in first «|»

Comment: Check your indentation. A tab is 8 spaces.

Comment: @chirlu, i use 4 spaces.

Comment: I think your guards need to be past the beginning of neighbour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guards have to be indented further than the name of the function they're part of, for example:

```
neighbours :: CityMap -> District -> [District]
neighbours (CM (_,rs)) b = mapMaybe neighbour rs
    where neighbour (p,q)
           | b == p    = Just q 
           | b == q    = Just p
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

This is because following the where, you're defining a (local) function `neighbour`, which has to also follow the layout rule; if the guard is further to the left, it's not a continuation of the definition of `neighbour`. You'd get the same error in a file that looked like this:

```
  neighbour (p,q)
| b == p   = Just q
```